# Unable to modify array parameter

Tags: perl

This is supposed to put the contents of `nums` into decreasing order, however `sort` does not change the contents of `nums`. Many sites I read have said to pass by reference, but I don't think I'm dereferencing the argument correctly. Bear with me, this is my first Perl program :)

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

sub sort {
    my @arr = @_;
    my $len = scalar @arr;

    for (my $i = 1; $i < $len-1; $i = $i + 1) {
        my $max = $i;
        for (my $j = $i + 1; $j < $len; $j = $j + 1) {
            if ($arr[$j] > $arr[$max]) {
                $max = $j
            }
        }
        $temp = $arr[$max];
        $arr[$max] = $arr[$i];
        $arr[$i] = $temp;
    }
}

print "Enter 10 numbers: ";
my $numbers = <STDIN>;
my @nums = split ' ', $numbers;

print "Unsorted: @nums\n";
sort \@nums;
print "Sorted: @nums\n";
```

Comment: `@_` contains one element, which is a reference to an array. Does that help at all?

Comment: It does make sense that it should be `my $arr = shift;`, however I put `print "@_\n"` at the top of `sort` and I get no output when I run it. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: `sort` is a built-in function in Perl, and that's what you're calling. There are ways to get around a user-defined function with the same name, but it's easier and better to just pick a different name.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering why `strict` was complaining about a useless call to `sort`. I figured out you get the values by calling `@$arr[..]`

Comment: Also, Perl arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: Yes I just noticed I copied that down wrong from my pseudocode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Matt Jacob helped me out with this one. This is what I was looking for.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

sub selection_sort {
    my $arr = shift;
    my $len = scalar @$arr;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $len-1; $i++) {
        my $max = $i;
        for (my $j = $i + 1; $j < $len; $j++) {
            if (@$arr[$j] > @$arr[$max]) {
                $max = $j
            }
        }
        my $temp = @$arr[$max];
        @$arr[$max] = @$arr[$i];
        @$arr[$i] = $temp;
    }
}

print "Enter 10 numbers: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;
my @integers = split ' ', $input;

print "Unsorted: @integers\n";
selection_sort \@integers;
print "Sorted: @integers\n";
```

Comment: This will work, but the more typical form of dereferencing that you'll see is `$arr->[$i]`

Comment: I had seen the operator but it said something about object members. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Are you sure you want to use array slices here?

Comment: @Shawn tbh, I don't know what those are unless you point them out.

Comment: `@foo[bar]` returns an array, not a single element of an array. See [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Comment: Your code only works at all because of this: *Slices in scalar context return the last item of the slice.* and being a bunch of 1-element slices. The more normal way would be to use scalars instead, either `$arr->[$i]` as was already mentioned, or `$$arr[$i]`.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`

Comment: Tip: `for (my $i = 0; $i < $len-1; $i++)` is better written `for my $i (0..$len-2)`. Similarly, the inner loop is better written `for my $j ($i+1..$len-1)`.

Comment: Tip: You don't need a temp to swap; you can use `($x,$y)=($y,$x);`

Comment: @Shawn, `@foo[bar]` returns scalars (not an array), and it could very well return a single element of an array. But it's seen as bad form to use a slice (`@a[$i]`) when an element lookup (`$a[$i]`) would suffice.

Comment: Also: you don't need the `scalar` in `my $len = scalar @$arr;`. Assigning an array to a scalar puts it in the scalar context so that its size is returned, so `my $len = @$arr;`.

Comment: another solution would be to pass the entire array to your function (not the reference) then returning it at the end of your sort. This way you can keep your original array untouched. you will be then calling your function this way: `my @sorted=selection_sort(@nums);` (this is how you use built-in `sort` function btw)